# How to estimate the mean knowing standard deviation?

Tags: confidence-interval, point-estimation

I want to estimate the mean and I have the next parameters:
Confidence Interval: 95%
Population Standard Deviation: 16.44
Maximum Error of the Estimate: 5

Comment: take a random sample from the relevant population and calculate sample average

Comment: I don't have a sample of data, just the standard deviation

Comment: This isn't possible.